# How to call sheet-specific macro from one Excel workbook in another?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to call an Excel macro that's in another workbook.  It's a sheet-specific macro, but the syntax given by Microsoft documentation and researching on the web, only gives a way to access a macro by workbook only.  That syntax is:

```
Application.Run ("testworkbook.xls!macroname")
```

What I need to do is have a sheet reference in there also, something like:

```
Application.Run ("testworkbook.xls!Sheet1.macroname")
```

I've tried this and MANY other variations, including having single or double quotes in there, but I always get the message that the macro cannot be found.

**Edit:**  With all the clues and much testing I found the answer.  You can access Sheet-specific subs, but you have to use the canonical name like 'Sheet1', you can't use the actual sheetname.  Apparently other workbooks don't access that information.

So the format above works as long as you don't try to use the sheetname (and you may have to single quote the workbook name (by concatenating `CHR(39)` to either end).

Comment: @Lance Roberts: does the answer below answer your question?

Comment: @Otaku, yes, though I ended up just using the canonical sheet name.  But I like all the info you give, so I'll accept your answer (I'd already upvoted it).

Comment: fair enough. i'm not sure if the canonical sheet name is the same for non-English UIs - if that is something you have to deal with - but it's quick and simple for these purposes. apprecaiate the accept/upvote.

Comment: @Otaku, yeh, I'm kind of throwing the word 'canonical' around, there may be a better term for it, it's just the way I think  of it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I know you've figured this out, probably after much hair-tearing and coffee, but I wanted to:

- Give you more details on why this is
- Provide you with a way you could use
  your sheet's name to get what you
  want.

First of all, the worksheet name you are wanting is not the same thing as the code module name. So in your VBE, you see that the name of the code module is "Sheet1", but if may have a different *property* of `Name` which is different, for example, "*MySheet1*" (or it also may be the same).

In order to get it by name, you'll have to do some loops, change security settings, etc. If that's what you're after (this works well in smaller environments because of the security setting issue), here you go as an example:

1. Change your security settings to
   trust programmatic access to VBA
   Projects. In Excel 2007, go to Orb | Excel Options | Trust Center | Trust Center Settings | Macro
   Settings and then enable "Trust
   access to the VBA project model"
2. Create a workbook with one
   worksheet. Rename it "*MySheet1*".
   Open the VBE (Alt+F11) and in
   "**Sheet1 (MySheet1)**" create a sub
   routine, call it `TimesTen` and in
   the code just put `Debug.Print 10 *
   10`. Like this:

   ```
   Sub TimesTen()
       Debug.Print 10 * 10
   End Sub
   ```
3. Save the file as an macro-enabled
   document and call it
   "*MacroXSLX.xlsm*". Leave it open.
4. Open a new Excel document, navigate
   to it's VBE and in a new macro
   anywhere, create a sub called
   `Test`. In the body of that code,
   put this:
   .

   ```
   Sub test()
   Dim SheetName As String
   SheetName = "MySheet1"
   Dim wb As Workbook
   Set wb = Workbooks("MacroXSLX.xlsm")
   For Each VBComp In wb.VBProject.VBComponents
       If VBComp.Properties.Item("Name").Value = SheetName Then
           Application.Run (wb.Name & "!" & VBComp.Name & ".TimesTen")
       End If
   Next
   End Sub
   ```
5. Press F5 to run `test` and you
   should see *100* in the Immediate
   window.

You can see in #4 that I'm looping through all the components (Modules, Classes, etc.) looking for the one that has a `Name` property that has a value of *MySheet1*. Once I have that, I can then get the name of that component, which in this case is *Sheet1* and use that to construct my string that will run the sheet's macro in *MacroXSLX.xlsm*. The code can be cleaned up further to exit the For statement when you've found what you want, etc.

As mentioned above, the only real draw-back to this is the security settings piece and ensuring you have programmatic access to the VBAProject - fine on one to ten computers, but could be a hassle if you have to ensure more than that are always set correctly.

Comment: Finally, I've found an answer that explains it, after 2 hours of hair-tearing and coffee. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

can you adjust your macro to accept a sheetname as a parameter?  Then when you call it within your original workbook's sheet you could just call it as MyMacro(me.name)?   Then when you call it from your other workbook, you could just call it as application.run("testworkbook.xls!MyMacro","sheetname")  where "sheetname" is your parameter.

I'm not sure if there is any other way to do it.

Comment: There are multiple sheets with the same button, and the same click event for them (so one per sheet).  My plan if I can't do it is to call the subroutine called by these macros directly (and insert the sheetname as a parameter in that).  I was just hoping I wouldn't have to go deeper to get the job done.

Comment: Well after looking closer I realized that the downstream parameter was the sheet itself, and you can't pass objects using the Run method.

Answer (score 1):

Does the VBA project have password protection? Also, is the sub a private sub? If so, then I don't believe the macro will be found.

Comment: The password protection is UserInterfaceOnly, so it shouldn't block the code.  The sub is Public.

Comment: UserInterfaceOnly affects whether code runs on a protected sheet or workbook. Having the VBA project password protected is different. But if it is a Public sub this shouldn't affect anything. Private subs can't be called from another module if the VBA project is protected.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

```
Run "'" & MySheet.Parent.name & "'!" & MySheet.CodeName & ".macroName"
```