# Open, run embedded macro, save, close, repeat for folder of .xslm files

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to run a macro that is embedded in each of 100 files without manually opening, running, saving, and closing them. The macro is only in the "target" files that I would like to run.

I found this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14766238/run-same-excel-macro-on-multiple-excel-files) on how to do this and gotten it to work locally.

```
Sub ProcessFiles()
    Dim Filename, Pathname As String
    Dim wb As Workbook

    Pathname = ThisWorkbook.Path
    Wildcard = "Target*.xlsm"
    Filename = Dir(Pathname & "\" & Wildcard)
    Do While Filename <> ""
        Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Pathname & "\" & Filename)
        DoWork wb
        wb.Close SaveChanges:=True
        Filename = Dir()
    Loop
End Sub

Sub DoWork(wb As Workbook)
    With wb
        'Do your work here
        .Worksheets(1).Range("A1").Value = "Goodbye World!"
    End With
End Sub
```

I put this VBA script in "Controller.xlsm" and I can run the `DoWork()` macro on a folder of target files with names like "Target1.xlsm", "Target2.xlsm", and so on. But I would like to replace `DoWork()` with a macro that is only in each of the targets (all the same macro, which calls software on this machine). I tried replacing `DoWork()` with things like `OtherMacro` and `Filename!OtherMacro`, but neither work (where `OtherMacro` is the identical macro in each of the "Target*.xlsm" files).

Is this possible? Can I run the macro in "Target*.xlsm" while looping through using a macro in "Controller.xlsm"?

It seems there's also the option to run the macro in "Target*.xlsm" and the others on open. If the macro in "Target*.xlsm" files requires 2 hours to run, will this cause problems? That is, will the macr in "Controller.xlsm" try to save and close "Target*.xlsm" before the work is done? Thanks!

Comment: Calling a sheet specific macro from outside the sheet: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2303436/212869 using this along with your loop should work

Comment: @NickSlash - Thanks. I should have thought of that. I am out the door now, but I'll try your solution this afternoon. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you need to specify the module that the macro is in. This should work:

```
Application.Run "'" & wb.name & "'!DoStuff"
```

Note that the workbook name must be enclosed in single quotes. And I think the macro in the target workbook must be Public.

Comment: Thanks, I'm out the door, but I'll try this afternoon.

Comment: It may help if the macro is public, but I could make it work with `Application.AutomationSecurity = msoAutomationSecurityLow`. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I had a play about with the link I added as a comment, it works but it does require you to change security permissions. If you know the name of the macro, and its location (module name) you should be able to just use `Application.Run`.

I tried without specifying the module name but it kept giving me an error.

```
Sub ProcessFiles()
    Dim Filename, Pathname As String
    Dim wb As Workbook

    Pathname = ThisWorkbook.Path
    Wildcard = "Target*.xlsm"
    Filename = Dir(Pathname & "\" & Wildcard)
    Do While Filename <> ""
        Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Pathname & "\" & Filename)
        Application.Run wb.name & "!Module1.DoStuff"
        wb.Close SaveChanges:=True
        Filename = Dir()
    Loop
End Sub
```

I'm sure `Application.Run` works like any other VBA sub, and that it will wait for it to complete before executing the next command but since there doesn't seem to be a way to return a value it might not? ( you are opening a new workbook in the same instance of excel so i think it should be ok )

Just re-read your question and I think you had the same question, if it is possible to modify your macros you could  remove the loop and use a queue instead. Have the macro either return a value to indicate its finished, or use the above code to call a sub in the master sheet to execute the next item.

Comment: Thanks, I'm out the door, but I'll try this afternoon. I hope it works without too much modification - I'm just getting started. :)

Comment: I couldn't get this to work with the module name (but I'm just getting started and don't yet understand the relation between modules and subs). I fixed the permissions problem with `Application.AutomationSecurity = msoAutomationSecurityLow`. After doing this Aardvark's approach worked fine.