# Can't set target worksheet from macro

Tags: vba, excel

I have this sub which processed macros that I added into 2 excel files and everything worked.

Now I've learned that the files that are to be processed won't have these macros and I should store them elsewhere. I put them in an empty workbook and I can call the macro.

The problem is, it's target is itself (an empty workbook). 
I need to to work on the Excel I have opened (x1)

It was originally

```
xl.Run macroName
```

the macro and target worksheets were contained here

Now I have this but I need it to run on the worksheets of x1, not itself.

```
myMacro.Run macroName
'runs but no worksheets here
```

Here is the full code of the sub

```
Sub prepareReport(macroName As String)

Dim myMacro As Object
Dim xl As Object

Dim filePath As String
Dim fileName As String

fileName = determineFileNameAuto(macroName)
filePath = CurrentProject.Path + "\source_files\" + fileName

'load macro-excel files
Set myMacro = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
myMacro.Workbooks.Open (myMacroFilePath)

'Load Excel file, then open the target workbook.
Set xl = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
xl.Workbooks.Open (filePath)

'Run the  macros

 'originally was
 'xl.Run macroName
 'macros were contained within file

'this will run but the target should be the x1 workbook
myMacro.Run macroName



' Close and save the workbook, then close Excel
echoBackToForm ("Closing Workbook")
   xl.ActiveWorkbook.Close (True)
   xl.Quit

'Step 5:  Memory Clean up.
Set xl = Nothing


End Sub
```

Comment: see [link1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2806065/running-excel-macro-from-another-workbook), [link2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15200349/trying-to-open-a-workbook-and-a-run-a-macro-in-that-file), [link3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2282925/how-to-call-sheet-specific-macro-from-one-excel-workbook-in-another)